# Joomla JTable map to existing table

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I've looked several places for this and don't see if there is a way anywhere. I want to map a JTable extension in Joomla to an existing table. for example in my class I have id but I want that to map to the Inventory_id column in my database. Does anyone know if that is possible?

Answer (score 0):

JTable is not built to remap columns. However, you can override the primary key in the constructor of the table class in your component:

```
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param JDatabase A database connector object
 */
public function __construct(&$db) {
    parent::__construct('#__your_component', 'primary_key', $db);
}
```